# Validation error on PayPal REST API

Tags: php, paypal

I'm trying to implement the PayPal REST API on a website, but I'm facing a validation error which I can't get out of. It has worked in the past with different values, but now I'm getting the following message:

> Transaction amount details (subtotal, tax, shipping) must add up to
>   specified amount total.

Here's the final bit, where I setup the `Transaction` object.

```
$transaction = new Transaction();
$transaction->setItemList($itemList)
            ->setAmount($amount);
```

Here's a `var_dump` of the `$itemList` and `$amount` objects:

```
object(PayPal\Api\ItemList)[1117]
  private '_propMap' (PayPal\Common\PayPalModel) => 
    array (size=1)
      'items' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => 
            object(PayPal\Api\Item)[1116]
              private '_propMap' (PayPal\Common\PayPalModel) => 
                array (size=4)
                  'name' => string 'Product description' (length=19)
                  'currency' => string 'EUR' (length=3)
                  'quantity' => int 1
                  'price' => string '31.90' (length=5)
object(PayPal\Api\Amount)[1119]
  private '_propMap' (PayPal\Common\PayPalModel) => 
    array (size=3)
      'currency' => string 'EUR' (length=3)
      'total' => string '137.46' (length=6)
      'details' => 
        object(PayPal\Api\Details)[1118]
          private '_propMap' (PayPal\Common\PayPalModel) => 
            array (size=2)
              'shipping' => string '105.56' (length=6)
              'subtotal' => string '31.90' (length=5)
```

I'm fairly certain that `105.56 + 31.90 = 137.46`, so there must be something else I'm overlooking. I process all values in cents and have to convert them to Euros to send to PayPal, but the `var_dump` shows that the conversion doesn't seem to be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to create a payment successfully with [PayPal-PHP-SDK](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK). What I did was modified the samples provided inside the sdk ([sample/payments/CreatePaymentUsingPayPal.php](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/blob/master/sample/payments/CreatePaymentUsingPayPal.php)), and made it to work with the details as per your question, and I was able to create it successfully.

Can you please compare, and see if you are not forgetting any step here.

```
<?php

// # Create Payment using PayPal as payment method
// This sample code demonstrates how you can process a 
// PayPal Account based Payment.
// API used: /v1/payments/payment

require __DIR__ . '/../bootstrap.php';
use PayPal\Api\Amount;
use PayPal\Api\Details;
use PayPal\Api\Item;
use PayPal\Api\ItemList;
use PayPal\Api\Payer;
use PayPal\Api\Payment;
use PayPal\Api\RedirectUrls;
use PayPal\Api\Transaction;

// ### Payer
// A resource representing a Payer that funds a payment
// For paypal account payments, set payment method
// to 'paypal'.
$payer = new Payer();
$payer->setPaymentMethod("paypal");

// ### Itemized information
// (Optional) Lets you specify item wise
// information
$item1 = new Item();
$item1->setName('Ground Coffee 40 oz')
    ->setCurrency('EUR')
    ->setQuantity(1)
    ->setSku("123123") // Similar to `item_number` in Classic API
    ->setPrice(31.90);

$itemList = new ItemList();
$itemList->setItems(array($item1));

// ### Additional payment details
// Use this optional field to set additional
// payment information such as tax, shipping
// charges etc.
$details = new Details();
$details->setShipping(105.56)
    ->setSubtotal(31.90);

// ### Amount
// Lets you specify a payment amount.
// You can also specify additional details
// such as shipping, tax.
$amount = new Amount();
$amount->setCurrency("EUR")
    ->setTotal(137.46)
    ->setDetails($details);

// ### Transaction
// A transaction defines the contract of a
// payment - what is the payment for and who
// is fulfilling it. 
$transaction = new Transaction();
$transaction->setAmount($amount)
    ->setItemList($itemList)
    ->setDescription("Payment description")
    ->setInvoiceNumber(uniqid());

// ### Redirect urls
// Set the urls that the buyer must be redirected to after 
// payment approval/ cancellation.
$baseUrl = getBaseUrl();
$redirectUrls = new RedirectUrls();
$redirectUrls->setReturnUrl("$baseUrl/ExecutePayment.php?success=true")
    ->setCancelUrl("$baseUrl/ExecutePayment.php?success=false");

// ### Payment
// A Payment Resource; create one using
// the above types and intent set to 'sale'
$payment = new Payment();
$payment->setIntent("sale")
    ->setPayer($payer)
    ->setRedirectUrls($redirectUrls)
    ->setTransactions(array($transaction));


// For Sample Purposes Only.
$request = clone $payment;

// ### Create Payment
// Create a payment by calling the 'create' method
// passing it a valid apiContext.
// (See bootstrap.php for more on `ApiContext`)
// The return object contains the state and the
// url to which the buyer must be redirected to
// for payment approval
try {
    $payment->create($apiContext);
} catch (Exception $ex) {
    // NOTE: PLEASE DO NOT USE RESULTPRINTER CLASS IN YOUR ORIGINAL CODE. FOR SAMPLE ONLY
    ResultPrinter::printError("Created Payment Using PayPal. Please visit the URL to Approve.", "Payment", null, $request, $ex);
    exit(1);
}

// ### Get redirect url
// The API response provides the url that you must redirect
// the buyer to. Retrieve the url from the $payment->getApprovalLink()
// method
$approvalUrl = $payment->getApprovalLink();

// NOTE: PLEASE DO NOT USE RESULTPRINTER CLASS IN YOUR ORIGINAL CODE. FOR SAMPLE ONLY
 ResultPrinter::printResult("Created Payment Using PayPal. Please visit the URL to Approve.", "Payment", "<a href='$approvalUrl' >$approvalUrl</a>", $request, $payment);

return $payment;
```

Here is the snapshot of the successful transaction:

[image]